# How to do a scale effect with min size (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, effects

I'm trying to add a scale effect when a popup appears. This popup is draggable (thanks to jQuery) and have only min-width and min-height but must **not** contains fixed size because the content can change dynamically (this is a sort of base popup which can be reusable for multiple popup content).

What I'm trying to do is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4b9joepk/4/) but actually I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dvm73sLk/3/)

```js
$('a.close').click(function() {
  $('#box').hide('scale', {
    percent: 0,
    direction: 'both',
    origin: ['middle', 'middle'],
  }, 1000);
});

$('#show').click(function() {
  $('#box').show('scale', {
    percent: 100,
    direction: 'both',
    origin: ['middle', 'middle'],
    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  background: #666666;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="show" id="show" class="show" value="Show">
<div id="box" style="display:none;">
  <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.
Léo

Comment: `min-width` and `min-height` - `200px`, `width` and `height` - `fit-content`, but keep in mind that `fit-content` has poor cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But if I put fit-content to the min-width/min-height, the box will lose his final size, and will be crop to the content "close"
And if I put fit-content to width/height, nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drop the min-height and min-width from box, and put a div inside it with content, the box will size to match the content. Then you can set the min-width and min-height to the content instead of the box.

[Here's a fork of your fiddle with the changes](https://jsfiddle.net/jamie_calder/q5p7dnux/2/).

```
/*HTML*/
<input type="button" name="show" id="show" class="show" value="Show">
<div id="box" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
    <div>
        THIS IS SOME CONTENT
    </div>
</div>

----------

/*CSS*/
#box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #666666;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}


#box div {
    padding: 30px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you're answer, this is exactly what I was looking for ! :)